# Mingw32-make fails with "Path not found" error

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, mingw32

I am trying to build a sample C++ project to get familiar with CMake on Windows (I am following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/heuristics/c-application-development-part-3-cmakelists-txt-from-scratch-7678253e5e24)), and I manage to generate the Makefile for MinGW using the command :

```sh
$ cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"
```

[This is the output Makefile](http://snippi.com/s/0zivuuk)

But then when I try to make that file using *mingw32-make*, it fails with the following error :

```sh
# the following line means "Path not found." in French
Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable.
Makefile:249: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
mingw32-make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

When I run *mingw32-make* with the `-d` flag, this is the output :

```sh
$ mingw32-make -d
GNU Make 3.82.90
Built for i686-pc-mingw32
Copyright (C) 1988-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
find_and_set_shell() path search set default_shell = C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile 'Makefile'...
find_and_set_shell() setting default_shell = cmd.exe
Updating makefiles....
 Considering target file 'Makefile'.
  Looking for an implicit rule for 'Makefile'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile,v'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile,v'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile'.
  No implicit rule found for 'Makefile'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file 'Makefile'.
 No need to remake target 'Makefile'.
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file 'default_target'.
 File 'default_target' does not exist.
  Considering target file 'all'.
   File 'all' does not exist.
    Considering target file 'cmake_check_build_system'.
     File 'cmake_check_build_system' does not exist.
     Finished prerequisites of target file 'cmake_check_build_system'.
    Must remake target 'cmake_check_build_system'.
Creating temporary batch file C:\Users\Ewaren\AppData\Local\Temp\make9944-1.bat
Batch file contents:
        @echo off
        "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -SC:\Users\Ewaren\Programmation\Tutos\sample_cmake -BC:\Users\Ewaren\Programmation\Tutos\sample_cmake\build --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
CreateProcess(C:\Users\Ewaren\AppData\Local\Temp\make9944-1.bat,C:\Users\Ewaren\AppData\Local\Temp\make9944-1.bat,...)
Putting child 02ac3a08 (cmake_check_build_system) PID 44864936 on the chain.
Live child 02ac3a08 (cmake_check_build_system) PID 44864936
Main thread handle = 00000138
Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable.
Reaping losing child 02ac3a08 PID 44864936
Cleaning up temp batch file C:\Users\Ewaren\AppData\Local\Temp\make9944-1.bat
Makefile:249: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
mingw32-make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Removing child 02ac3a08 PID 44864936 from chain.
```

I do not understand *what path* is referred to in the error message, could someone help me out ? Thanks.

Comment: Please, show output of commands run with [LC_ALL=C prefix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/105594). Such way we would understand all phrases in the log, not the ones you have explicitly translated.

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand what you mean, all the log is already in English except for the one single phrase that I mentioned. Since then, I have installed the regular "make" from MSYS and that one works, as opposed to "mingw32-make".